# Support for more than 64bit signed integers

Tags: google-bigquery, custom-data-type

Bigquery currently supports [64 bit signed integers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) in its tables. Is there any plan to increase this size limit.

If a user or a company wants to add/create a new data type eg. 128bit unsigned integer. How can one proceed to integrate it with bigquery?

Use-case --> I am making a [data analytics platform](https://www.analyseether.com) to analyse transactions on a blockchain. A blockchain has a token supply limit 10^s and a decimal 10^d for each token. So theoretically we can have a maximum transaction (as an integer) worth 10^(s+d). As an example ether has ~10^8 supply and 10^18 decimal for each ether. On top of that anyone can write his own token in a smart contract with [variable *s* and *d*](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/blob/master/tokens/tokens-eth.json) . Thus the need for a variable length data type.

Numeric --> I checked out the numeric(38,9) proposal but for our use case (temporarily) we would prefer numeric(38,0).

PS. I would be really interested of you can propose a method to split this into two columns.

Comment: Can you say more about your use-case? Depending on what you are trying to do, maybe storing two `INT64` columns would work, or maybe you can use the `NUMERIC` type ([currently in alpha](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906014)).

Comment: Ankit Chiplunkar, you need to @ElliottBrossard, otherwise he won't know you have edited the post.

Comment: If you want NUMERIC but without a fractional part, it seems like you could just use the type in any case but only store integers using it. Does that not work?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard currently numeric has the integer part for 10^(38-9 = 29) integers. This can be accepted for ethereum where the maximum transactional value is of order of 10^(18+8 = 26) but not acceptable for other tokens such as Kin 10^(14+18 = 32).
Would saving the integer part of the transactions and decimal part of the transaction in two seperate columns be an advisable solution?

Comment: That seems like it could work. You could use a STRUCT with two fields, potentially.

Comment: If you have a solution or workaround, kindly post it as an answer so other people could benefit from it.

Comment: @XiaoxiaLin Currently, STRUCT looks as the most viable solution. I will try it out and then put the solution. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @elliott-brossard we tested out STRUCT type and we would the arithematic operations provided by INTEGER, FLOAT or NUMERIC datatypes. I have hence filled out the request form to get access to NUMERIC datatypes in its alpha stage